# Java implicit Overloading

Tags: java, overloading

Let's say I have a method called *order*(), which receives 3 parameters (arg0, arg1, arg2) and determine whether arg0 < arg1 < arg2. I want this method to be able to work on both integers and Strings. How should I perform the overloading? instead of declaring:

```
 1. order(int, int, int) 
 2. order(int, String, int)
 3. order(int, int, String)
 4. order(int, String, String)
 5. order(String, int, int)
 6. order(String, String, int)
 7. order(String, int, String)
 8. order(String, String, String)
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't have overloads, force the caller to convert everything to `int` first. How would your `Order` method handle `"hello world"` as an input?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? In which cases is an integer smaller than a String?

Comment: you can parse `String` into `int` through `Integer.parseInt()` and compare. BTW why do you want methods to overload, declare one signature `order(int, int, int)` so that a caller pass `int` values always and rest logic you implement in your function. Handle the exceptions as per you logic.

Comment: This is just an example. My question is to track whether I can do any implicit overloading, instead of declaring ridiculous amount of methods or forcing the user to convert the values first. I need this for totally different purposes, not to compare ints with strings.

Comment: It is unclear why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not do implicit conversions (except widening conversions on numeric types). If you're working with your own custom types, then you could have them implement a common interface. Otherwise, you just have to bite the bullet and write out all the overloads, or make the user convert them all to a common type.

Answer (score 0):

The common property of the parameters you want to order is that you must be *comparable* to each other. 
Therefore, your method should rather accept three `Comparable` items, which would allow the caller to pass ints (that would be automatically wrapped as `Integers`) and `Strings`, among others.

```
public <T> boolean order(Comparable<T> item1, Comparable<T> item2, Comparable<T> item3)
```